# C# Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty

Tags: c#, json, linq

I was hoping you guys may be able to assist in helping me out. I would like to pull every ID within the JSON file however I am getting the following exception error:

> Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string address = "https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nba/2016-2017-regular/cumulative_player_stats.json?team=85";
        var w = new WebClient();
        w.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        w.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("****", "****");
        var result = w.DownloadString(address);

        var obj = JObject.Parse(result);
        var play = "";


        foreach (JProperty child in obj["cumulativeplayerstats"])
        {
            play = child["player"]["ID"].ToString();

            string latlong = Convert.ToString(play);
            Console.WriteLine("player=" + Convert.ToString(play));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Here is a snippet of what the json looks like:

```
{
  "cumulativeplayerstats": {
    "lastUpdatedOn": "2017-09-11 4:45:30 PM",
    "playerstatsentry": [
      {
        "player": {
          "ID": "10138",
          "LastName": "Abrines",
          "FirstName": "Alex",
          "JerseyNumber": "8",
          "Position": "F"
        },
        "team": {
          "ID": "96",
          "City": "Oklahoma City",
          "Name": "Thunder",
          "Abbreviation": "OKL"
        },
        "stats": {
          "GamesPlayed": {
            "@abbreviation": "GP",
            "#text": "68"
          },
          "Fg2PtAtt": {
            "@category": "Field Goals",
            "@abbreviation": "2PA",
            "#text": "94"
          },
          "Fg2PtMade": {
            "@category": "Field Goals",
            "@abbreviation": "2PM",
            "#text": "40"
          },
          "Fg3PtAtt": {
            "@category": "Field Goals",
            "@abbreviation": "3PA",
            "#text": "247"
          },
          "Fg3PtMade": {
            "@category": "Field Goals",
            "@abbreviation": "3PM",
            "#text": "94"
          },
          "FtAtt": {
            "@category": "Free Throws",
            "@abbreviation": "FTA",
            "#text": "49"
          },
          "FtMade": {
            "@category": "Free Throws",
            "@abbreviation": "FTM",
            "#text": "44"
          }
        }
      },
```

I tried digging around on here but I cant seem to find a solution that works. If you guys can lend some of your sage wisdom, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks Folks!

Comment: Just a guess here, but could it be puking when looking at the first child of `cumulativeplayerstats`, which is  `"lastUpdatedOn": "2017-09-11 4:45:30 PM",`, There is no `player` node under that node...

Comment: @TylerLee I thought the same, but when i updated  

play = child["lastUpdatedOn"].ToString();

I still received the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your `foreach` to iterate through the `playerstatsentry` array:

```
foreach (JObject child in obj["cumulativeplayerstats"]["playerstatsentry"].OfType<JObject>())
```

Or without the `OfType<T>`:

```
foreach (var child in obj["cumulativeplayerstats"]["playerstatsentry"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking your JSON as an example, if you are trying to locate all the properties named "ID", provided they are at same level of the hierarchy, you can utilize the *"SelectTokens"* method using path and wildcards to reach to your property level. This will probably save a few lines of code and is a better way to locate.

.net Fiddle for this solution - https://dotnetfiddle.net/fQ9xeH

```
foreach (var tokn in obj.SelectTokens("cumulativeplayerstats.playerstatsentry[*].*.ID"))
{               
    Console.WriteLine(tokn);
}
```

Comment: Please accept this as an answer if it worked for you.